# Why do we need document instance to create an xml Element in java?

Tags: java, xml, dom, w3c

I have a programming logic where I have to create two XMLs through one function.

Each tutorial that I have seen online follows a specific procedure to create an XML. I have written the following code to create XML in Java:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder =documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlDocument= documentBuilder.newDocument();
Document anotherXmlDocument= documentBuilder.newDocument();
Element rootElement = xmlDocument.createElement("root");
Element anotherRootElement = anotherXmlDocument.createElement("root");// reduntant line
xmlDocument.appendChild(rootElement);
anotherXmlDocument.appendChild(anotherRootElement);
```

Is the 6th line not redundant? What is the significance of document to create an `Element`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** - an XML Document was deliberately designed as a factory for its own elements because it's a special type of Node: it also points to the convention about what one should expect from the structure of the document.

> What is the significance of document to create an Element?

To make a distinction between an XML document and just an element floating around. Making from a document a "factory of elements" is a design decision made on purpose by the specification of the [XML Document Object Model](https://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) since the very beginning and a decision that is embedded in its [core](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-core.html)

The reason for this design choice, is that what you ask? Well, XML/HTML is about structured data, using tags to delimit the structure into what is otherwise a linear text document. This structure is intended to make easier the textual information processing **and exchange** (without loosing the readability by human eyes).

Now, the *information exchange* is the important bit here: since XML (and its ancestor - [SGML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language)) allows one to define their own structure, the exchange of XML documents needs to be preceded by the setting up a convention between the exchanging parties on what is will be the structure and what semantic this structure will impose on the marked-up text (semantic example: like `<h1>`, `<h2>` etc are headers, `<em>` will mean the text is emphasized, and a `<table>` will contain 2D-tabulated data instead of a linear flow of text, etc).

This convention is to be formulated by either (old style) [DTD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition) (that's Document Type Definition - works for SGML as well) or an [XSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)) (that's XML Schema Definition). When I'm sending to another party and XML *document*, the XML specification says I must send a bit of information pointing to one of the DTD or XSD, so the receiving party will know what convention I'm adopting for the structure of the document.

So, a Document node will contain only one element (the root one), it will be able to create other Element nodes (as a factory) but it is the responsibility of the programmer to *insert the created nodes in the appropriate places*, so that the resulted document will be valid against the agreed structure. If you look at the specification of the [`Document` type of DOM-node](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-core.html#i-Document), you'll note that it has and attribute named `doctype`: this attribute is meant to contain the extra information about the convention on the document structure (in effect, this `doctype` will point to the DTD or XSD containing the description of the document structure)

---

(whew)

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks. Better now?

Comment: Yes, much better.

Answer (score 1):

In the XML tree there are namespace definitions and there might be a DTD or schema attached that describes which elements are allowed. Tag names may be Unicode letters when the xml version is above 1.0.

More likely however it is that the `org.w3c.Document` is a very old, external non-`java. ...` API, which one can see from many features, children, children count, needed casts etcetera. Such validation on creation might have been considered *(fail-fast)*, but personally I think Document is an interface defined as standard, and specifies the most bureaucratic requirement: that the construction goes via the document.

Comment: But is there a better way of doing what i just did?
I dont really like that i have to write reduntant code to append same element.

Comment: @Aragorn - like it or not, this is how [the specification was defined](https://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR). You are free however to write your own library which will create XML documents in a more expeditious manner - many did in the early days, but nowadays XML becomes more of a niche than a mainstream in data exchange (JSON is leading, YAML slowly slides into an aged-care type of use, XML remains around mainly in configuration-files-with-intricate-structure than in data exchange - you see, JSON doesn't yet have a solidly defined Schema definition and the same validation toolset as XML).

Answer (score 1):

`Document` and `Element` are interfaces in the `org.w3c.*` API. So there is no way to actually directly instantiate them. There is a default Java implementation that ships with the Java runtime, but there are probably others out there that implement the interfaces. The `createElement` logic is there in part also because using factories to instantiate objects was far more common when this API was first created.

It's an old API and goes back to the time when it was very common in the groups that use Java to think of abstracting out details like these interfaces "just in case you want to switch implementations." It now sounds insane because why on Earth would you switch XML implementations between the built-in XML API and a third party one that implements the same interfaces. Yet that is how a lot of developers saw such things in the late 90s and early 00s.